# Go RPC Error: reading body gob: attempt to decode into a non-pointer

Tags: go

When I call RPC, this error will happen. 
While on the server side, I can get the call successfully.

Answer (score 9):

The error is defined at https://golang.org/src/encoding/gob/decoder.go
As the error says, decoder need a pointer.

The wrong rpc call  is `call(address, name, args, reply)`. Server can receive the call successfully while can not reply, the rpc call fails.

The right way is `call(address, name, args, &reply)`